# Formatting Manipulate output to have 2 cells in Mathematica

Tags: module, wolfram-mathematica

The following output code outputs an array from the manipulate statement.  I would like to output the fitting and plot as two separate output cells that update dynamically.  I think it should be pretty simple, but I am having trouble with it.  I've tried using the CellPrint[] function, but did not get it to work.
Thanks,
Tal

```
temperatures(*mK*)= {300, 200, 150, 100, 75, 50, 25, 11, 10};

F[t_, \[Nu]_] := t^\[Nu];

rd (*uOhms*)= {27173.91304, 31250., 42372.88136, 200601.80542, 
   1.05263*10^6, 1.33333*10^7, 1.33333*10^8, 2.*10^8, 2.1*10^8};

logRd = Log10[rd];

f[\[Nu]0_] := Module[{\[Nu]},
  \[Nu] = \[Nu]0;
  data = Transpose[{F[temperatures, \[Nu]]*10^3, logRd}];
  fitToHexatic = LinearModelFit[data[[4 ;; 6]], x, x];
  plota = 
   Plot[fitToHexatic["BestFit"], {x, 0, data[[-1]][[1]]}, 
    Axes -> False];
  plotb = ListPlot[data, Axes -> False];
  {fitToHexatic, Show[{plota, plotb}, Axes -> True]}
  ]

Manipulate[
 f[nu],
 {nu, -0.2, -1}
 ]
```

Screenshot of the output:

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a Manipulate.  You can get more control with lower level functions.  E.g.

```
Slider[Dynamic[nu, (f[#]; nu = #) &], {-0.2, -1}]
Dynamic[Normal[fitToHexatic]]
Dynamic[Show[{plota, plotb}, Axes -> True]]
```

See also [Prototypical Manipulate in lower level functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4878/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-prototypical-manipulate-in-lower-level-functions).

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks :)  I also got it to work by putting each of my statements inside a Row[] function.  Then, it outputs all of them from the Manipulate.